# Elegant way to calculate first generator result larger than X

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator and would like to find out what the first value which it generates larger than X. One way to do this is as follows, but it seems rather long-winded (it reads like it repeats itself).

```
def long_winded(gen,X)
    n = next(gen)
    while n < X: n=next(gen)
    return n
```

What I wanted to write was something more simply:

```
short_broken(gen,X):
    while next(gen)<X: pass
    return next(gen)            # returns the SECOND value larger than X, as gen is called again
short_broken2(gen,X):
    while n = next(gen)<X: pass # Not python syntax!
    return n
```

Is there a pythonically-concise way to return the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def short2(gen,X):
    for x in gen:
        if x > X: 
            return x
```

or as a 1-liner (which I prefer to the itertools variant):

```
def short3(gen,X):
    return next(x for x in gen if x > X)
```

---

*my original answer -- left only for the sake of posterity*

I'm not necessarily asserting that this method is better, but you can use a recursive function:

```
def short(gen,X):
    n = next(gen)
    return n if n>X else short(gen,X)
```

Comment: Which is elegant, but a bad idea if you're going to have generators where you have to check more than a thousand elements (or more than whatever you set your maximum recursion limit to).

Comment: Ah ha! It was an obvious candidate for recursion. :) but unfortunately @Wilduck's point is a good one.

Comment: @Wilduck's point is definitely a good one -- its why I prefaced my comment by saying "I'm not necessarily asserting that this method is better" ... which a weak way of saying -- "I doubt that I would use this in my code".

Comment: @hayden -- I've also added 2 other varients.

Comment: +1 for the genexp version (though I'd use `dropwhile` myself, but I was ninja'd again).  @hayden: when programming in Python, I only use recursion when dealing with nested data objects where I know in practice it won't be more than 10 or so levels deep.  For everything else I think in terms of iteration and `yield`ing values from stateful generators.

Comment: @DSM -- you'd prefer `dropwhile + lambda` to a simple genexp?

Comment: @mgilson The other variants were exactly what I was looking for, astonishingly I didn't think you could for loop through a generator (even though I knew about `xrange`)! Thanks! :)

Comment: @hayden -- Yep.  In some respects, that's what generators are for :-)

Comment: @mgilson I knew I was missing something, and this was exactly it! :)

Comment: @mgilson: no, I think I actually prefer yours, but I can't deny my first instinct was `dropwhile`.

Answer (score 8):

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def first_result_larger_than_x(gen, X):
    return next(dropwhile(lambda n: n <= X, gen))
```

Note that your code examples from the OP are actually returning the first result greater than *or equal to* X. I've corrected that in this code example, but if that was what you actually wanted, change the `<=` to a `<`.

Comment: Thanks, as usual itertools is the business! I did say greater than in the title (I suspected it didn't matter to much to the actual answer :) ).

Comment: Itertools seems to be way overkill here ... `next(x for x in gen if x > X)` is essentially the same thing without itertools and a lambda function ...